# The best way to capture the output of a file itself in unix

Tags: bash, file, unix, scripting, output

I have this script here say abc.sh that looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
date
echo a
echo b
echo c
...
```

And the output will be

```
a
b
c
....
```

what I'm trying to achieve here is, to use a command at the end of the file, to capture the output of the file and then redirect to the output.txt. I don't want to add >> to append every single echo to the output file as I don't think it will be a good practice. or maybe is there a way to encapsulates all the output commands and redirect them to the file? something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
date
echo a
echo b
echo c
...
} > output.txt
```

Can this be done using just one script? or must I use another script to call abc.sh >output.txt?

Comment: Why not `abc.sh >output.txt`. And you may use `tee` to display on both screen and export to output.txt: `abc.sh |tee output.txt`

Comment: I know I can do that, but can I just have the script to handle those?

Comment: you can set a function called oecho,  content is `echo $1 > output`, replace all echo in your script to oecho.

Comment: How doesn't what you have work?

Comment: what about the other outputs that came from commands such as date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you gave using curly brackets works just fine exactly the way you posted it.

Another way is adding literally `exec > output.txt` as the second line (after the shebang) in your script. All subsequent output in the script will be redirected to the file.

Comment: oh wow, I never tried that out as I thought It'll be too naive to think that will work.